# Arduino: how do I pass a String constant into a char array?

Tags: c, arduino, type-conversion

I have noticed that variables with a data type of String use way more memory than C strings do, so I'd like to use C strings wherever possible. However I've run into a problem casting a String constant into a C string when I call a method with a C string parameter.

This is what I'm trying to do but I keep getting a warning that I'm using a deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*'. How do I do the conversion correctly?

```
void drawButton(int x, int y, int width, int height, char text[ ]) {
  // do some stuff
}

void loop() {
  drawButton(30, 70, 150, 50, "Continue");
}
```

Comment: 1) Try `char text[ ]` --> `const char text[ ]`.  Perhaps it is the `const` that the warning is depreciating.  2) Better to post exact text of the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You should either create a char array variable and pass that as a parameter or you can create a method to convert the string and lastly you can pass `{ 'C', 'o', 'n', 't', 'i', 'n', 'u', 'e'}`, if that works in C.

Comment: wouldn't creating a char variable and passing that create two variables in memory for every button I create? That seems really wasteful of resources.

Comment: True that, since you work with C you could use a pointer. Also, it's text for a button. So it would be even better to have a global variable,`char[] buttonContinue`, for example and than pass `char[] *buttonContinue`. As I said, not so much experience with C. So you probably have to write it differently.